# Kendo Grid Not Displaying Spinning Icon or loading icon

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, icons, loading

The following is my grid code

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
                                .Name("Grid")
                                        .Columns(columns =>
                                        {
                                             //columns                                             
                                        })
                                     .Pageable()
                                     .Sortable()
                                     .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(430))
                                     .Filterable(filterable => filterable
                                                  .Extra(false)
                                                  .Operators(operators => operators
                                                       .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                                                            .Contains("Contains")
                                                            .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                                                            .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
                                                            .StartsWith("Starts with")
                                                            .DoesNotContain("Does not contain")
                                                    ))
                                                    )

                                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Controller"))
                                    .Create(update => update.Action("Create", "Controller"))
                                    .PageSize(10)
                                    .Model(m =>
                                    {
                                        // Fields
                                    })
                                    .ServerOperation(false)
))
```

While it is taking time to get data from database through specified read action, the spinning or loading icon not displayed within the grid. I find some articles on SO itself regarding this stating that the height must be set and otherwise set `min-height` using the css class `.k-grid-content`. But I already set height for the grid in `Scrollable` and even I tried suggestions specified in different articles, none of them worked for me. Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: have you included all relevant content files/ scripts for your application? Do you get any missing resources notifications in the developer tools within the browser? To me it sounds like you are not including some of the content files within you product. You could also try setting the height via the htmlAttributes.

Comment: When the grid is loading, does it actually have the height you defined? If not, you might need to actually set `min-height` as you mentioned

Comment: @David Shorthose and @user1102901 I included all content files and scripts. I am not getting any error in the developer tools within the browser. My grid is displayed with same height I set and I also tried by setting `min-height'. But it didn't worked.